# Adding to a list in a loop

Tags: python

I have recently started learning programming and I'm trying to use what I am learning.

What I am trying to do: I am trying to write a program that will pick positive numbers from a list and add them to an empty list.

The code I wrote:

```
lst = [5, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5]

lst2 = []

for i in lst:

    if i > 0:

        lst2=lst2.append[i]

    if i <= 0:

        break

print(lst2)
```

This is my first piece of code, and I would appreciate any form of response. Thank you!

Comment: That looks like a great start!  What issue are you running into?

Comment: `lst2 = lst2.append(i)` does not work - it will set lst2 to None as append() does not return anything.. simply use `lst2.append(i)`. And  `break` will leave the for loop - you probably want to `continue` with the next number instead - in case there are other numbere after a non-positpive one you still need to add (`lst = [5, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, 9, 7]`).  `lst2 = [x for x in lst if x > 0]` would be the shorthand to keep any number of lst in its order if greater 0.

Answer (score 6):

That's a good start! A few things:

1. `list.append` does not *return* a modified list, it appends the item to the list directly and returns `None`. So you don't want to say `lst2 = lst2.append(...)`, just do the `append` call and that's enough. Also, you need parentheses `()` and not brackets `[]` for function calls.
2. You don't want to call `break` since it'll quit the whole loop, so if there are any more positive numbers after the first negative is encountered they'll just get skipped. In fact, you don't even need the second `if` at all, the first one is enough to do what you want.

So:

```
lst = [5, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5]
lst2 = []

for i in lst:
    if i > 0:
        lst2.append(i)

print(lst2)
```

The more 'pythonic' way of doing this is by using a list comprehension, which looks like this:

```
lst =  [5, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5]
lst2 = [i for i in lst if i > 0]
```